Simple/Efficient way of drawing plots for the modulation method of a inverter
I am trying to draw something like this with pgfplots right now:

But it is very time-consuming, especially if I have to do a few variants of it. So I was wondering how I can do it more efficiently. I was writing and calculating every single point by hand. So far I have this, and I am not even close to what the above picture looks like:
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=3cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=6.2831,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$t$,
    % ylabel=$\sin x$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=west,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=east,
    },
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:6.2831,samples=200,thick, cyan] {sin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[blue] coordinates {(0,-1) (0.5235,1) ( 1.0471,-1) (1.570,1) (2.094,-1)};
    % \addplot[red] coordinates {(0,-1) (1,1) (2,-1) (3,1) (4,-1)};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(2, -1.5) (2, 1.5)};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(5, -1.5) (5, 1.5)};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(8, -1.5) (8, 1.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=3cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$t$,
    % ylabel=$\sin x$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=west,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=east,
    },
    ]
    % \addplot[domain=0:10,samples=200,thick] {cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(2, -1.5) (2, 1.5)};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(5, -1.5) (5, 1.5)};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(8, -1.5) (8, 1.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=3cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$t$,
    % ylabel=$\sin x$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=west,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=east,
    },
    ]
    % \addplot[domain=0:10,samples=200,thick] {sin(deg(x)) * cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(2, -1.5) (2, 1.5)};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(5, -1.5) (5, 1.5)};
    \addplot[red, thick] coordinates {(8, -1.5) (8, 1.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


Can anyone lead me into a different direction, so I don't have to draw everything manually by hand? This will otherwise take me days of work for a few diagrams.

Welcome. // Have a look here https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing . And here for examples https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-timing

To change view, we need to perceive your drawing from a different perspective. Let's dicard the noisy sine and saw part for the moment and build the diagram in reverse. Then all digital signals are just: 1) a y-t axis, 2) a set of boxes with fill color. So let's drop pgfplots and use Tikz (it's base). // The background coloration ain't difficult either, if you know Tikz. // If you CAN specify the handful of on-off-times, the boxes are easy to place. I'd use a different program to calculate these. // Finally draw those sine and saw: all will fit now.

Here is something to get you started, following my outline in the comment: derive intersections of sine and saws outside of Tikz/Latex AND take these points in time as input here (it certainly can be done here as well, but introduces more compelxity for little benefit).
Please consider the code as an intermediate state, because this way I can show you both process and results. Results have two components:

the "printed" drawing
the beautified code

It may be a good idea to look up things in the pgfmanual in parallel. Please find the full code at the end.

Background stripes
This is simple enough: you just draw rectangles with some fill color. The style bggn is defined at the start of the tikzpicture environment. Changes there will keep uniformity. \tmab etc. are just numbers, see Refactoring below.
Thinking in terms of repetition it's enough to draw one side with dashed lines.
These 4 lines of code can and should be refactored into a \newcommand later. Then you can draw any number of stripes.
 % ~~~ background stripes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % --- to be refactored into a \newcommand ----------
    % ~~~ drawing some T3-backgrounds /green) ~~~~~~
    \draw[bggn] (\tmab,0) rectangle (\tmae,5);
    \draw[bggn] (\tmbb,0) rectangle (\tmbe,5);
    
    % ~~~ left (only !)dashed boundaries ~~~~~~
    \draw[dshd] (\tmab,0) -- +(0,5);
    \draw[dshd] (\tmbb,0) -- +(0,5);

Axis
It's the next simple thing, though it may appear strange. Let's look at the commetned-out part first:

draw a line between 3 points
put arrow tips at both ends
put some labels (\node{}) at the 3 coordinates
finally, finish this path by ;

    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   \draw[<->] (0,\tfour + .8) 
%                      node[ancl]{EIN} 
%                      node[xshift=-14mm,yshift=-4mm] {T3} --
%              (0,\tfour) node[ancl]{AUS} -- 
%              (8,\tfour) node[ancr] {$t$};
    \axs{\tthree}{T3}   % refactored: code now in \newcommand
    \axs{\ttwo}  {T2}   

Once that worked (with some numbers) I moced its code into \newcommand\axs{2]{}, which takes two parameters. By doing so though I started with T3 it's now easy to add T2 for example.
Signals
The signals are similar to the background stripes: just a series of rectangles. Just specify:

where one puls starts
where its origin is on the canvas
where it stops
which style to use

    % ~~~ signal ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   \draw[sgbl] (\tmab,\tthree) rectangle (\tmae,\tthree + .6);
%   \draw[sgbl] (\tmbb,\tthree) rectangle (\tmbe,\tthree + .6);
     
     % T3
    \pls{\tmab}{\tthree}{\tmae}{sgbl}
    \pls{\tmbb}{\tthree}{\tmbe}{sgbl}
    
    % T2
    \pls{\tmaab}{\ttwo}{\tmaae}{sgrd}
    \pls{\tmabb}{\ttwo}{\tmabe}{sgrd}

Thinking ahead (refactoring) this part perhaps is a candidate for a loop construct.
Refactoring
General strategy
Refactoring is a way to create efficient code, which more often then not has a kind of beauty to it. What you do is:

start simple (see my commented out codes)
summarize, once the same things are used at least twice (or will be in a minute)
clean-up code (i.e. remove those commented-out transitory lines: go from ugly to more beautiful)

Parameters
In this code there are 3 types of parameters:

timing related (where a pulse starts and stops)
layout related (where to put its starting point)

As you can see \axs and \pls still have constants: these may or may not be refactored while you continue this diagram, like axis-height, pulse-height etc.
Outlook
Adding more signals, pulses and stripes should be straight forward now.
Adding sine and saws basically is just another \draw action, where at least the sine can be done using \draw ... plot ...; As long as you add new things step-by-step, compile often, backup often, there is little that can bring you off track. Don't forget to ... refactor frequently.

% ~~~ defining "numerical" shortcuts (begin, end) ~~~~~~~~~
\def\tmab{1}    \def\tmae{1.5}
\def\tmbb{5}    \def\tmbe{5.6}

\def\tmaab{0}   \def\tmaae{.8}
\def\tmabb{2}   \def\tmabe{2.5}


% ~~~ y-coordinate of axis origin ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\tthree{1.5}
\def\ttwo{3.5}

% ~~~ simplifying drawing things ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\axs[2]{%
    \draw[<->] (0,#1 + .8) %
                       node[ancl]{EIN} %
                       node[xshift=-14mm,yshift=-4mm] {#2} --%
               (0,#1) node[ancl]{AUS} -- %
               (8,#1) node[ancr] {$t$};}
               
\newcommand\pls[4]{\draw[#4] (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#2 + .5);}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bggn/.style={fill=green!40,draw=none},  % stripes
    dshd/.style={dashed},                   % left border
    >={Stealth},                            % niceer arrow tip
    ancr/.style={anchor=north west},        % label anchors
    ancl/.style={anchor=east,font={\small\bfseries\sf}},
    sgbl/.style={draw=blue!100!black!50,    % blue digital signal
                 fill=blue!60,
                 line width=2pt},
    sgrd/.style={draw=red!100!black!50,     % red digital signal
                 fill=red!60,
                 line width=2pt},
 ]
 % ~~~ background stripes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % --- to be refactored into a \newcommand ----------
    % ~~~ drawing some T3-backgrounds /green) ~~~~~~
    \draw[bggn] (\tmab,0) rectangle (\tmae,5);
    \draw[bggn] (\tmbb,0) rectangle (\tmbe,5);
    
    % ~~~ left (only !)dashed boundaries ~~~~~~
    \draw[dshd] (\tmab,0) -- +(0,5);
    \draw[dshd] (\tmbb,0) -- +(0,5);
    
 % ~~~ digital signals ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ signal ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   \draw[sgbl] (\tmab,\tthree) rectangle (\tmae,\tthree + .6);
%   \draw[sgbl] (\tmbb,\tthree) rectangle (\tmbe,\tthree + .6);
     
     % T3
    \pls{\tmab}{\tthree}{\tmae}{sgbl}
    \pls{\tmbb}{\tthree}{\tmbe}{sgbl}
    
    % T2
    \pls{\tmaab}{\ttwo}{\tmaae}{sgrd}
    \pls{\tmabb}{\ttwo}{\tmabe}{sgrd}

    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   \draw[<->] (0,\tfour + .8) 
%                      node[ancl]{EIN} 
%                      node[xshift=-14mm,yshift=-4mm] {T3} --
%              (0,\tfour) node[ancl]{AUS} -- 
%              (8,\tfour) node[ancr] {$t$};
    \axs{\tthree}{T3}   % refactored: code now in \newcommand
    \axs{\ttwo}  {T2}   
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Here the same code without uncommented lines, i.e. cleaned-up, a bit more beautiful:
% ~~~ defining "numerical" shortcuts (begin, end) ~~~~~~~~~
\def\tmab{1}    \def\tmae{1.5}
\def\tmbb{5}    \def\tmbe{5.6}

\def\tmaab{0}   \def\tmaae{.8}
\def\tmabb{2}   \def\tmabe{2.5}


% ~~~ y-coordinate of axis origin ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\tthree{1.5}
\def\ttwo{3.5}

% ~~~ simplifying drawing things ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\axs[2]{%
    \draw[<->] (0,#1 + .8) %
                       node[ancl]{EIN} %
                       node[xshift=-14mm,yshift=-4mm] {#2} --%
               (0,#1) node[ancl]{AUS} -- %
               (8,#1) node[ancr] {$t$};}
               
\newcommand\pls[4]{\draw[#4] (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#2 + .5);}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bggn/.style={fill=green!40,draw=none},  % stripes
    dshd/.style={dashed},                   % left border
    >={Stealth},                            % niceer arrow tip
    ancr/.style={anchor=north west},        % label anchors
    ancl/.style={anchor=east,font={\small\bfseries\sf}},
    sgbl/.style={draw=blue!100!black!50,    % blue digital signal
                 fill=blue!60,
                 line width=2pt},
    sgrd/.style={draw=red!100!black!50,     % red digital signal
                 fill=red!60,
                 line width=2pt},
 ]
 % ~~~ background stripes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % --- to be refactored into a \newcommand ----------
    % ~~~ drawing some T3-backgrounds /green) ~~~~~~
    \draw[bggn] (\tmab,0) rectangle (\tmae,5);
    \draw[bggn] (\tmbb,0) rectangle (\tmbe,5);
    
    % ~~~ left (only !)dashed boundaries ~~~~~~
    \draw[dshd] (\tmab,0) -- +(0,5);
    \draw[dshd] (\tmbb,0) -- +(0,5);
    
 % ~~~ digital signals ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ signal ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
     % T3
    \pls{\tmab}{\tthree}{\tmae}{sgbl}
    \pls{\tmbb}{\tthree}{\tmbe}{sgbl}
    
    % T2
    \pls{\tmaab}{\ttwo}{\tmaae}{sgrd}
    \pls{\tmabb}{\ttwo}{\tmabe}{sgrd}

    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \axs{\tthree}{T3}
    \axs{\ttwo}  {T2}   
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you. This was actually very helpful.

Let's take my previous approach a step further: How do you arrive here?

General remarks
As you can see, the new things are:

all stripes
previous digital signals, with new adjustments
the relevant part for the analog signals
the code is expanded and refactored again

I assume you now can add these yourself:

add an axis for the analog signals
put the colored names on top of the stripes

Get the times (somehow)
The previous definitions of times were ok, but lack generality. So let's have a look at the following diagram, which shows one way to derive the required points in time:


measure the x-coordinate in pixels (black text)
rescale it to useful dimensions in centimeters (lower part; I used R, but you can use any better alternative, like Excel, a circuit simulator etc.)
top row: "enumerate" the starting times for y-ellow, r-ed, g-reen and c-yan

The reason for the latter is: you can't have e.g. \def\t1{}, as numbers aren't allowed here. So we need a systematic like \def\tay, \def\tra etc. Consulting this systematics makes it easy to draw the various things.
New set of constants
... for times and layout related dimensions (recall previous diagram).
% ~~~ times for the colored stripes ~~~~~~~~
\def\tya{0.00}      \def\tra{0.42}  \def\tga{0.70}
\def\trb{1.30}      \def\tyb{1.96}  \def\trc{2.22}
\def\tgb{3.10}      \def\trd{3.18}  \def\tyc{4.06}
\def\tre{4.32}      \def\tgc{4.98}  \def\trf{5.58}
\def\tyd{5.84}      \def\tgd{6.28}  \def\tca{6.70}
\def\tye{6.94}      \def\tcb{7.56}  \def\tge{8.26}
\def\tcc{8.48}      \def\tyf{9.36}  \def\tcd{9.48}
\def\tgf{10.34}     \def\tce{10.60} \def\tyg{11.24}
\def\tcf{11.88}     \def\tgg{12.12} \def\tend{12.52}

% ~~~ y-coordinate of axis origin ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\yana{9}
\def\ytwo{3.5}
\def\ythree{1.5}

% ~~~ layout paramters ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\strh{12}   % height of colored stripes
\def\axwd{13}   % width of the axes

Analog signals
 % ~~~ analog signals ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ sine = piecewise sin, cos, see ch.14.10 ~~~
% \draw (0,0) sin(3.13,1) cos(6.26,0) sin(9.39,-1) cos(12.52,0);
    \draw[sn] (0,\yana) sin(3.13, 1+\yana) cos( 6.26,\yana)
                        sin(9.39,-1+\yana) cos(12.52,\yana);
                        
    % ~~~ saw teeth ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    \draw[rt]  ( 0,1+\yana) -- ( 1.04,-1+\yana) -- 
            ( 2.09,1+\yana) -- ( 3.13,-1+\yana) --
            ( 4.17,1+\yana) -- ( 5.22,-1+\yana) -- 
            ( 6.26,1+\yana) -- ( 7.30,-1+\yana) --      
            ( 8.35,1+\yana) -- ( 9.39,-1+\yana) -- 
            (10.43,1+\yana) -- (11.48,-1+\yana) --      
            (12.52,1+\yana);
...

For the sine it's a bit peculiar, as Tikz provides short segments to draw sin or cos. However, it's quite convenient: you just draw segment after segment, switching.
The commented line shows you my development, which draws the sine at the bottom. Adding the required shift \yana puts it on top.
Please not that all amplitudes are fixed to 1. If you want to have more flexibility, introduce ... a constant for it.
Each saw tooth also is just one path of wiggling a line up and down. This may be done more elegantly, but it's still easy enough to follow this way. // The other one just needs inverted amplitudes.
Slight timing mismatches
If you look carefully there are some mismatches betweent the analog signals, their intersections and colored stripes. This is a numerical effect I introduced. To resolve it, go from 2 decimals (as I used) to 3 or more. Here's my result from R:
> 12.52 / 12 * seq(1:12)
 [1]  1.043333  2.086667  3.130000  4.173333  5.216667  6.260000  7.303333  8.346667  9.390000 10.433333 11.476667
[12] 12.520000

Or just conceal it by using even slightly larger line widths.
Digital signals
 % ~~~ digital signals ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ signal ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   first implementation
%   % T2
%   \pls{\tya}{\ttwo}{\tra}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tyb}{\ttwo}{\trc}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tyc}{\ttwo}{\tre}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tca}{\ttwo}{\tge}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tcc}{\ttwo}{\tgf}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tce}{\ttwo}{\tgg}{sgrd}
    
    % ~~~ T2, refactored ~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \b/\e in {
        \tya/\tra, \tyb/\trc, \tyc/\tre,
        \tca/\tge, \tcc/\tgf, \tce/\tgg
    } \pls{\b}{\ytwo}{\e}{sgrd};

The first implementations shows you, what works safely.
Introducing \foreach and specifying pairs of data \b/\e simplifies this one. Here parameters are \b and \e, delimiter is /. The loop runs trough a list of pairs, calling \pls every time.
Refactoring, which may be useful to do

the saw teeth calculations should be improved
you may want to absorb the code for T2 and T3 into a new \newcommand (3 parameters: list of pairs, y-offseet, style)

The colored stripes will be hard if impossible to refactor into something shorter.

Code; don't forget to consult above's scheme for naming conventions:
% ~~~ times for the colored stripes ~~~~~~~~
\def\tya{0.00}      \def\tra{0.42}  \def\tga{0.70}
\def\trb{1.30}      \def\tyb{1.96}  \def\trc{2.22}
\def\tgb{3.10}      \def\trd{3.18}  \def\tyc{4.06}
\def\tre{4.32}      \def\tgc{4.98}  \def\trf{5.58}
\def\tyd{5.84}      \def\tgd{6.28}  \def\tca{6.70}
\def\tye{6.94}      \def\tcb{7.56}  \def\tge{8.26}
\def\tcc{8.48}      \def\tyf{9.36}  \def\tcd{9.48}
\def\tgf{10.34}     \def\tce{10.60} \def\tyg{11.24}
\def\tcf{11.88}     \def\tgg{12.12} \def\tend{12.52}

% ~~~ y-coordinate of axis origin ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\yana{9}
\def\ytwo{3.5}
\def\ythree{1.5}

% ~~~ layout paramters ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\strh{12}   % height of colored stripes
\def\axwd{13}   % width of the axes

% ~~~ simplifying drawing things ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\axs[2]{%    axis
    \draw[<->] (0,#1 + .8) %
                       node[ancl]{EIN} %
                       node[xshift=-14mm,yshift=-4mm] {#2} --%
               (0,#1) node[ancl]{AUS} -- %
               (\axwd,#1) node[ancr] {$t$};}
               
\newcommand\pls[4]{\draw[#4] (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#2 + .5);}% pulse

\newcommand\cstr[3]{%   colored stripes
    \draw[#1]   (#2,0) rectangle (#3,\strh);% filled rectangeö
    \draw[dshd] (#2,0) -- +(0,\strh);}      % left dashed line

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bggn/.style={fill=green!25, draw=none}, % stripes
    bgyl/.style={fill=yellow!25,draw=none},
    bgrd/.style={fill=red!25,   draw=none},
    bgcy/.style={fill=cyan!25,  draw=none},
    dshd/.style={dashed},                   % left border
    >={Stealth},                            % niceer arrow tip
    ancr/.style={anchor=north west},        % label anchors
    ancl/.style={anchor=east,font={\small\bfseries\sf}},
    sgbl/.style={draw=blue!100!black!50,    % blue digital signal
                 fill=blue!60,
                 line width=2pt},
    sgrd/.style={draw=red!100!black!50,     % red digital signal
                 fill=red!60,
                 line width=2pt},
    sn/.style={cyan,line width=1.8pt},      % sine
    rt/.style={red,line width=1.5pt},       % red saw tooth
    bt/.style={blue,line width=1.5pt},      % blue saw tooth
 ]
 % ~~~ background stripes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ drawing some backgrounds ~~~~~~
    \cstr{bgyl}{\tya}{\tra} \cstr{bgrd}{\tra}{\tga} \cstr{bggn}{\tga}{\trb}
    \cstr{bgrd}{\trb}{\tyb} \cstr{bgyl}{\tyb}{\trc} \cstr{bgrd}{\trc}{\tgb}
    \cstr{bggn}{\tgb}{\trd} \cstr{bgrd}{\trd}{\tyc} \cstr{bgyl}{\tyc}{\tre}
    \cstr{bgrd}{\tre}{\tgc} \cstr{bggn}{\tgc}{\trf} \cstr{bgrd}{\trf}{\tyd}
    \cstr{bgyl}{\tyd}{\tgd} \cstr{bggn}{\tgd}{\tca} \cstr{bgcy}{\tca}{\tye}
    \cstr{bgyl}{\tye}{\tcb} \cstr{bgcy}{\tcb}{\tge} \cstr{bggn}{\tge}{\tcc}
    \cstr{bgcy}{\tcc}{\tyf} \cstr{bgyl}{\tyf}{\tcd} \cstr{bgcy}{\tcd}{\tgf}
    \cstr{bggn}{\tgf}{\tce} \cstr{bgcy}{\tce}{\tyg} \cstr{bgyl}{\tyg}{\tcf}
    \cstr{bgcy}{\tcf}{\tgg} \cstr{bggn}{\tgg}{\tend}

 % ~~~ analog signals ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ sine = piecewise sin, cos, see ch.14.10 ~~~
% \draw (0,0) sin(3.13,1) cos(6.26,0) sin(9.39,-1) cos(12.52,0);
    \draw[sn] (0,\yana) sin(3.13, 1+\yana) cos( 6.26,\yana)
                        sin(9.39,-1+\yana) cos(12.52,\yana);
                        
    % ~~~ saw teeth ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    \draw[rt]  ( 0,1+\yana) -- ( 1.04,-1+\yana) -- 
            ( 2.09,1+\yana) -- ( 3.13,-1+\yana) --
            ( 4.17,1+\yana) -- ( 5.22,-1+\yana) -- 
            ( 6.26,1+\yana) -- ( 7.30,-1+\yana) --      
            ( 8.35,1+\yana) -- ( 9.39,-1+\yana) -- 
            (10.43,1+\yana) -- (11.48,-1+\yana) --      
            (12.52,1+\yana);
            
    \draw[bt]  ( 0,-1+\yana) -- ( 1.04,1+\yana) -- 
            ( 2.09,-1+\yana) -- ( 3.13,1+\yana) --
            ( 4.17,-1+\yana) -- ( 5.22,1+\yana) -- 
            ( 6.26,-1+\yana) -- ( 7.30,1+\yana) --      
            ( 8.35,-1+\yana) -- ( 9.39,1+\yana) -- 
            (10.43,-1+\yana) -- (11.48,1+\yana) --      
            (12.52,-1+\yana);
        
 % ~~~ digital signals ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ signal ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   first implementation
%   % T2
%   \pls{\tya}{\ttwo}{\tra}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tyb}{\ttwo}{\trc}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tyc}{\ttwo}{\tre}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tca}{\ttwo}{\tge}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tcc}{\ttwo}{\tgf}{sgrd}
%   \pls{\tce}{\ttwo}{\tgg}{sgrd}
    
    % ~~~ T2, refactored ~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \b/\e in {
        \tya/\tra, \tyb/\trc, \tyc/\tre,
        \tca/\tge, \tcc/\tgf, \tce/\tgg
    } \pls{\b}{\ytwo}{\e}{sgrd};

    % T3
    \foreach \b/\e in {
        \tga/\trb, \tgb/\trd, \tgc/\trf,
        \tgd/\tye, \tcb/\tyf, \tcd/\tyg,
        \tcf/\tend
    } \pls{\b}{\ythree}{\e}{sgbl};  

    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \axs{\ytwo}  {T2}   
    \axs{\ythree}{T3}
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

